# Can't get DHCP offers in a bridge network in virtualbox(win10host/ubuntuguest)?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp, bridging

I have tried almost every solution that claims to solve this problem.

1. Firstly in VirtualBox settings, I changed the network adapter setting to Bridge Network and choose the network interface I am connected which is Atheros wireless Adapter.
2. Then I entered the guest ubuntu machine and have done the following:

   `vim /etc/network/interfaces`
   and edited the file as:

```
    auto ens0p3
    iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

3. `sudo ifdown ens0p3`, `sudo ifup ens0p3`

But it showed it cannot get the DHCP offers.

My host machine is windows 10 and in command prompt I get the following information by `ipconfig -a`:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : AP.BlockC.BoysHostel
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-FF-28-1F-CE-9D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6c59:f1c7:dbcf:de9b%16(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.100.58.95(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, May 23, 2019 4:51:12 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, May 23, 2019 6:43:07 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.100.58.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.100.58.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 298385192
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-AD-59-8C-54-AB-3A-68-EC-13
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 103.5.150.9
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

3. Also, I tried the static IP configuration approach in my Ubuntu guest.
   I can now ping to host system from guest and guest system from host.
   But while accessing to the internet, I can ping the IP address of google.com, facebook.com but can't access them by names like ping google.com, ping facebook.com.

Also I can't access the sites in the browser in the guest machine.

4. But when I change the adapter setting back to NAT, everything works well but it assigns me with an ip of 10.0.2.15. But I want a bridge network connection to get an ip from my gateway for network learning application.

So, please help me with this problem. It has been 3 days I am constantly trying in this problem.